# How to add Snazzy maps Javascript Style array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

can someone help me to Add Snazzy map style to my react project.
I have successfully loaded my map. Now i want to add snazzy map style to it.

the style i want to add is: https://snazzymaps.com/style/38/shades-of-grey

My code is as follows

```
            <Map 
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={20}
            bootstrapURLKeys={{
                key: 'AIzaSyCbwAIiqBpdHLZ1Isdc5kXqQagCoerKbEg'
            }}
            style={""}
            className="map"
            initialCenter={{
                lat: 10.010533, 
                lng: 76.365536
              }}
            >
```

Comment: Seems that asking a question here is quicker than reading the docs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a free coding service or a place to request links to documentation.

Comment: Why are you so furious brother ? 

Been looking for a solution for the last two hours . Just trying to learn here

Comment: what have you tried? what's the issue? you can easily pass style object or array to style prop

Comment: im trying to push in a specific style 

you can get the array of  style in the link.

but when  i tried to push it in its not giving me any changes

Answer (score 0):

Tried a diffrent syntax and got it working .

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"

const stylesArr = [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}];
const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY&callback=initMap",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={15}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 10.010533,lng: 76.365536 }}
    defaultOptions={{ styles: stylesArr }}

  >
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: 10.010533,lng: 76.365536 }} />}
  </GoogleMap>
)

export default MyMapComponent;
```